# single valued analytic branch of multivalued function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, branch-cuts, multivalued-functions

Consider $f(z)=\sqrt{z\sin z}$. Can $f(z)$ be defined near the origin as a single valued analytic function?

How do we choose the branch cut. The answer is here http://math.nyu.edu/student_resources/wwiki/index.php/Complex_Variables:_1999_September:_Problem_4 
but this is not comprehensible

Comment: Yes, if you restrict "near the origin" to defined by $|z|<R$, for $R<\pi$ since there are branch point singularities at $z=n\pi$ for all non-zero integer values of $n$ (i.e. the zeros of $\sin z$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $z \sin z = z^2 g(z)$, where $g(z) = \frac{\sin(z)}{z}$.  Since $g$ has a removable singularity at $0$ by defining $g(0) = 1$, we can define a single valued square root of $g(z)$ in a neighborhood of $0$.  Thus we get $f(z) = z \,\sqrt{g(z)}$.

Comment: +1, but perhaps you should explicitly say "we can define a single valued square root of $g(z)$ in a neighborhood of $0$" because the completed $g$ is near $1$ when $z$ is in the neighborhood of zero. The branch cut is then defined at the negative real axis (away from $1$) but is not needed.

Comment: The branch cuts will have to take into account where ever $g(z) = 0$.  So the sensible thing would be to take a branch cut at $(-\infty,-\pi] \cup [\pi,\infty)$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith thanks for the answer. Can you explain more why we can define a single valued square root of $g$ when we have removable singularity. Also, for what you said above, we must move the branch cut to $(-\infty, -\pi]$ and $[\pi, \infty)$ to ensure the analyticity right?

Comment: It's not that the singularity is removable - its also that the value at that point is non-zero.  Then you see that there is a neighborhood $N$ of $0$ such that $g(N)$ is in a small enough neighborhood of $1$ that the square root can be defined in a single valued manner.

Comment: However, proving that there is a single values square root of $g$ on all of $\mathbb C \setminus((-\infty,-\pi] \cup [\pi,\infty))$ probably requires the monodromy theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy_theorem

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith thanks that explains very well

Comment: Hi @StephenMontgomery-Smith, from writing $zsin(z) = z^2g(z)$, how do you get $f(z) = z \sqrt {g(z)}$?  Isn't the square root of $z^2$ ... |z|?  And also, why do we need two branch cuts?  Thanks,

Comment: @User001 I am not taking **the** square root, I am taking **a** square root.  Also, if $z$ is complex, then the square roots of $z^2$ are $\pm z$.  The formula $\sqrt{z^2} = |z|$ is only valid if $z$ is real.

Comment: Ok got it -- thanks so much for your help @StephenMontgomery-Smith.  Very cool solution :-)